# WebSQL and LocalStorage error after update to Android WebView

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, cordovawebview

I have a cordova app for android. On 30th April 2015 Google pushed an update to the webview and since then things are going haywire. The localstorage is getting cleared automatically when the app starts.

This is unexpected behaviour. If someone has had this problem before, it would be really kind if you could guide me through this. The problem here is since the localstorage is vanishing, I cannot keep a track of the db version for the websql.

Comment: For me it's not clear what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @Joop: There is an issue for Cordova/Phonegap apps using WebView on Android Lollipop (The WebView is auto-updated in Lollipop), which clears the LocalStorage on app restart. If LocalStorage is cleared there is no place to easily store data for Cordova based apps. The WebView in the latest update is thus broken and is leading to a lot of problems.

Comment: Can you please share some code? Also, maybe consider building a super simple app that just reads a localStorage value, increments it, and saves it. See if that demo (should take you 5 minutes to write) can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Experiencing the same issues with many of our cordova app's. Many Android 5.0 users reporting this crazy behavior which was actually really hard to diagnose.

[Android 5.0 - localStorage not being persisted](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481380)

> It's already fixed in WebView 42.0.2311.138 which is released to the
>   beta channel and hopefully will be rolling out to stable soon.

However only viable solution for now seems to be '**uninstalling the updates for android system webview**'.

Comment: This issue has been fixed. I was experiencing the issue and it ruined a lot of things for us. After the update was released, it got fixed. The last time looked it up the apps were working fine.

Comment: well it's not for me yet, i have updated to android 5.1.1 and after updating my device 'android system webview' version is still at 42.0.2311.121 and the issue still persists on my app's. can you confirm your device 'android system webview' version that includes the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pretty big deal for some. This link makes me think that the problem cannot be solved easily.  You'd have to NOT use the function/feature of WebView until Google releases update. Crazy. There's a manual fix that works well, but you'd have to do that on every phone.

So what’s the fix? Uninstall the most recent update of Webview. On most phones, that means jumping into Settings>Applications (Manager)> and then finding Android System Webview, tapping on, and then uninstalling the latest update. You can see a picture of this screen at the top of this post. While that’s not exactly the greatest fix, because this latest update did introduces “stability and security fixes,” it might save your phone in the interim.

http://www.droid-life.com/2015/04/27/apps-crashing-android-system-webview/

Comment: But this fix only for individual users. My app gets distributed to a group of individuals, I cannot ask them all to remove webview. This would indeed be a very manual solution.